# How to implement custom pagination with LINQ2Entities using 1 call to the database

Tags: pagination, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I am working on `ASP.NET Web Forms` project and I use `jquery datatable` to visualize data fetched from `SQL` server. I need to pass the results for the current page and the total number of results for which by far I have this code :

```
var queryResult = query.Select(p => new[] { p.Id.ToString(), 
                                            p.Name, 
                                            p.Weight.ToString(),
                                            p.Address })
                                            .Skip(iDisplayStart)
                                            .Take(iDisplayLength).ToArray();
```

and the result that I get when I return the result to the view like :

```
iTotalRecords = queryResult.Count(),
```

is the number of records that the user has chosen to see per page. Logical, but I haven't thought about it while building my Method chaining. Now I think about the optimal way to implement this. Since it's likely to use with relatively big amounts of data (10,000 rows, maybe more) I would like leave as much work as I can to the `SQL` server. However I found several questions asked about this, and the impression that I get is that I have to make two queries to the database, or manipulate the total result in my code. But I think this will won't be efficient when you have to work with many records.

So what can I do here to get best performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to what you’re looking for I don’t think there is a simple answer.

I believe the only way you can currently do this is by running more than one query like you have already suggested, whether this would be encapsulated inside a stored procedure (SPROC) call or generated by EF.

However, I believe you can make optimsations to make your query run quicker.

First of all, every query execution MAY result in the query being recached as you are chaining your methods together, this means that the actual query being executed will need to be recompiled and cached by SQL Server (if that is your chosen technology) before being executed.  This normally only takes a few milliseconds, but if the query being executed only takes a few milliseconds then this is relatively expensive.

Entity framework will translate this Linq query and execute it using derived tables.  With a small result set of approx. 1k records to be paged your current solution maybe best suited.  This would also depend upon on how complex your SQL filtering is as generated by your method chaining.

If your result set to be paged grows up towards 15k, I would suggest writing a SPROC to get the best performance and scalability which would insert the records into a temp table and run two queries against it, firstly to get the paged records, and secondly to get the total results.

```
alter proc dbo.usp_GetPagedResults
    @Skip int = 10,
    @Take int = 10
as
begin

    select
        row_number() over (order by id) [RowNumber],
        t.Name,
        t.Weight,
        t.Address
    into
        #results
    from
        dbo.MyTable t

    declare @To int = @Skip+@Take-1
    select * from #results where RowNumber between @Skip and @To
    select max(RowNumber) from #results

end
go
```

You can use the EF to map a SPROC call to entity types or create a new custom type containing the results and the number of results.
[Stored Procedures with Multiple Results](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj691402.aspx)

I found that the cost of running the above SPROC was approximately a third of running the query which EF generated to get the same result based upon the result set size of 15k records. It was however three times slower than the EF query if only a 1K record result set due to the temp table creation.

Encapsulating this logic inside a SPROC allows the query to be refactored and optimised as your result set grows without having to change any application based code.

The suggested solution doesn’t use the derived table queries as created by the Entity Framework inside a SPROC as I found there was a marginal performance difference between running the SPROC and the query directly.